# When I reduce owl carousal width then showing empty space items before and after navigation

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

When I reduce owl carousal width then showing empty space items before and after navigation

My code is here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider-wrap').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 3,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  touchDrag  : false,
  mouseDrag  : false
});

$('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
$('.slider-wrap').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
var slidIndex = (e.item.index + 1) - e.relatedTarget._clones.length / 2;

if(slidIndex == 1){
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('background-color','yellow');
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
}
});

});
```

```css
.item{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  
}
.owl-item {
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-wrap owl-carousel">
     <div class="item">
      1
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      2
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      3
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      4
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      5
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      6
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

When I reduce owl carousal width then showing empty space items before and after navigation.

My Owl Carousel picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you put your code ins Stack snippet or JS fiddle.

Comment: Harshsetia,thanks dear, please see, I am adding my code

Comment: Snippet is not working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue i work on my local. SO please tell me the issue.

Comment: please check again , now Snippet is working, if you run this then I think you can understand my issue

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you desire you don't need to change carousel item width instead increase the number of `item` in JS so that it adjust itself, please see below fiddle for more understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider-wrap').owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  items: 10,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  touchDrag  : false,
  mouseDrag  : false
});

$('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
$('.slider-wrap').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
var slidIndex = (e.item.index + 1) - e.relatedTarget._clones.length / 2;

if(slidIndex == 1){
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('background-color','yellow');
  $('.slider-wrap .owl-stage').css('transform','translateX(0)');
}
});

});
```

```css
.item{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="slider-container">
                <div class="slider-wrap owl-carousel">
                    <div class="item">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        4
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        5
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        6
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```